# Encoding JSON with strings in html data attributes

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-templates

I need to pass some data to javascript. So I've created a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import template
import json

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def mydata():
    return mark_safe(json.dumps([("a", 1), ("b", 2)])
```

Then in my template,

```
<div id="mydata" data-stuff="{% mydata %}" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Which is used in a js file with jquery loaded:

```
$('#mydata').data('stuff') //automatically does JSON.parse
```

The problem is the quotes from `"a"` and `"b"` break the HTML attribute syntax. I can simply change to single quotes (`data-stuff='{% mydata %}'`) but is there a more definitive django approach to injecting JSON into the template? Perhaps something like an `escape_my_json` or `escape_for_html_attribute` function.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact it is a bit hacky to store json in attribute, single-quotation (apostrophe , U+0027) is not a valid string delimiter in [JSON](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt). Some browsers may have problems with this, although I cannot point out any.

If the JSON struct is not complex store every field as a separate data-*, otherwise in JS.

If you need to use attribute... really, really ...I would not replace quotes (simple replace will be loosy) more likely encode it with base64.

Note about escaping: To escape double-quotes (single as well) you can use filter [addslashes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#addslashes) (or in python [django.template.defaultfilters.addslashes](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L65)), but it is not json data aware so it may break.

Comment: OK, so you recommend `<script>var mydata = JSON.parse('{% mydata %}');</script>`? I'm surprised that jquery explicitly tried to parse `data-` attributes as JSON if it's considered so hacky. Also I meant use single quotes for the attribute rather than within the JSON.

Comment: even without JSON.parse since JSON object is valid JS object `var mydata = {% mydata %};`