# How to convert "['2022-03-24', '2022-03-25']" to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, django-templates

I want to convert `"['2022-03-24', '2022-03-25']"` to javascript array data is from `element.dataset`

did `const dateRange = JSON.stringify("['2022-03-24', '2022-03-25']")`
`JSON.parse(dateRange)` returns `['2022-03-24', '2022-03-25']` which is a string and not a javaScript array.

I want to populate date range with `flatpickr` with object from my database so I'm passing the date html element via data attribute `<input type="date" class="date-range" data-date="{{date_range}}" />`

Comment: make the original string is valid JSON (use double quotes) and then just parse it. `JSON.parse('["2022-03-24", "2022-03-25"]')`

Comment: No; using parse directly on it throws this error VM24785:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at (index):531:30
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at flatpickrDate ((index):530:19)
    at (index):541:5

Comment: As i said, make sure it's valid first (double quotes, not single around array elements). Also see: [Encoding JSON with strings in html data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215369/encoding-json-with-strings-in-html-data-attributes)

Comment: also: [Using JSON in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286192/using-json-in-django-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that, it would leave you with array of date strings, try to parse them to dates now (if you need).

```
someString.replace(/[',\]\[]/g, '').split(' ')
```

Comment: The scary regex to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Function()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) object to create an instance of a function that will return an array. The second line below creates an anonymous function which is then immediately invoked via `()`.

```
const arrString = "['2022-03-24', '2022-03-25']";
const arr = (new Function(`return ${arrString}`))();
console.log( arr );
```

**DEMO**

```js
const arrString = "['2022-03-24', '2022-03-25']";
const arr = (new Function(`return ${arrString}`))();
console.log( arr );
```